# Run existing macro on a new Google Sheet with least number of clicks

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macro

How to execute an existing macro (or any other kind of script) on a **new** Google Sheet with the least number of clicks/keystrokes?
Or even automatically when opening it?

*Context*: My bank sends me a **new** Google Sheet **each day**, and I need to execute the same few basic calculations inside it, taking me a minute each day. These operations can be macro'd easily, so I would love a way to execute the macro quickly.

Comment: Use **Copy to...** in the tab bar to copy the new sheet to your existing spreadsheet and run the existing macro there.

Comment: @doubleunary: Great idea, could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: My comment does not answer the question "_How to execute an existing script function on a new Google Sheet_". It just mentions one solution to the underlying problem you have. These two things are not the same, and Stack Exchange is a question-answer wiki site rather than a problem-solution discussion forum.

Answer (score -1):

As a baseline, here is my current way of importing macros, it is unfortunately very time-consuming:

1. Click `Extensions` then `Apps Script`.
2. Wait for 10 seconds until the UI is fully loaded.
3. CTRL-A.
4. CTRL-C to paste the macro you prepared.
5. CTRL-S to save.
6. CTRL-W to close the Apps Script tab.
7. Click `Extensions` then `Macros` then `Import macro`.
8. Click `Add function`.
9. Ckick `X` to close the dialog.
10. Click `Extensions` then `Macros` then the imported macro.
11. A `Authorization Required` dialog pops up, click `Continue`.
12. A `Choose an account` dialog pops up, click your account.
13. A `Google hasn’t verified this app` dialog pops up, click `Advanced` then `Go to [...]`.
14. A `[...] wants to access your Google Account` dialog pops up, scroll down to reveal the `Allow` button then click it.
15. Click `Extensions` then `Macros` then the imported macro again, as the authorization cancels the first run.

It takes 18 clicks, 4 keystrokes, 1 scroll and a lot of waiting.

Faster solutions very welcome!

Comment: This answer should be instead an edit to your question, it is essentially your current research that you have found unacceptable.

Comment: I would argue that it is a solution, albeit a time-consuming one. Once better solutions appear and get upvoted, they will be more visible than this one. :-)

Comment: You stated in your question that "current way I know to import the existing macro requires too many clicks/keystrokes for it to be time-efficient." and I assume that is a very long detailed description of the approach you find unacceptable but if you think it is an answer to the question posed by the person that indicated that it wasn't an acceptable answer to the question, who am I to argue.  I'll let you two sort it out :-)

Comment: Haha you are right, I am inconsistent, thanks for pointing this out. I guess I should frame the question as "what is the fastest way?" rather than judge what is acceptable or not. I will try to edit the question, looking forward to your feedback (and sorry for editing the question rather than getting it right the first time).